# How to strip multiple lines in a list

Tags: python, list

```
list_ex=['accidentally,cancel,order,please,thank',
 'add,address',
 'add,address,aged,date,order,put,thank,update,way,would',
 'add,address,appreciate,change,help1,like,much,please,would',
 'add,address,appreciate,order,receive,refund,thank,would']
```

and I want to output it like

```
['accidentally','cancel','order','please','thank','add','address','add','address','aged','date','order','put','thank','update','way','would','add','address','appreciate','change','help1','like','much','please','would','add','address','appreciate','order','receive','refund','thank','would']
```

I tried like this

```
converted_list=[]
for element in list(list_ex):
    converted_list.append(element.strip('\n'))
set(converted_list)
```

not getting desired output

Comment: Your attempt doesn't work because the list items (strings) do not contain any NewLines (\n), so there is nothing to strip. I am not exactly sure what you want to do to be honest. Is it really just about the printing?

Comment: Uhh you literally just print the list to get the desired output. Am I missing something obvious here? Also, don't shadow the built-in `list` keyword. Name your list something else.

Comment: Até you sure this is the output you want? It looks Just like the list printed, nothing special.

Comment: The difference between your input and output is not related to newlines. In the output, the input strings have just been split by comma.

Comment: I think you mean `split` not `strip`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over `list_ex` and split each string on comma:

```
out = []
for string in list_ex:
    out.extend(string.split(','))
```